# train the object detection model on images with 1 object and test it with images with multible objects

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I'm trying to make a dataset of images for object detection model, and I don't know if I can train the model in images that condtain only the object and the cordinate will be the full image, and test it on an images that contain multible objects for example:
the training images look like:

[train-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbBqd.jpg)

[train-img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwHAM.jpg)

[test imags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBECA.jpg)

will this effect the localization somehow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the training images. If your training images (all of them) exactly the ones you uploaded the accuracy of your model on the test images will not be good. In fact in real world scenarios all the training images will not be identical and should have a lot of variation in order for you to generalize your model better.

Comment: thank you (:
I have many images and the idea is that i have 10000 images of 5 classes that contain many objects at each, i want to train a model on  1000 images that i manually annotate and then let the model detect object on other images and crop the objects and automatically save them in classes folder, then the images now are one object per image and the boundry box of each is the full image sizee for example ( 0,0 - 600,600) if we assume that the images size is 600*600 

i hope i have explained clearly

Comment: when you are doing so, I would suggest you to add some non-annotated (higher percentage the better, lets say around 30 to 40%) pictures in each class. that way you will get better results I presume.

Comment: yes thank you,  of course for the final model all the images will be there includeing the ones that i have annotated manually. 
I'm asking if the idea is fine

Comment: Yes, Your approach is reasonable

Comment: Thank you @mkpisk